# Tor use frequent entry nodes after each launch

Tags: guard-node

After launching Tor I can see in my firewall logs there are always few IPs that i'm connecting to. Is this something normal? These are entry nodes right? But why always the same? Does Tor cache something? I think on windows this problem doesn't happen.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.xx and  Tor 2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tor will only use a few entry relays to minimize the risk that you use a hostile entry relay: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#EntryGuards

Answer (score 1):

It is not choosing the same Entry Node each time. Instead it is getting information about the state of the Tor Network.

Before Tor can connect to Entry nodes, it has to find out about what nodes are on the network. It does this by downloading the consensus from a few fixed computers. Because this step has to happen without any other Tor information being available the IP addresses of these select computers are hard-coded into Tor. After it has downloaded the consensus over the regular internet, it will then select an Entry Node at random to begin forming secure Tor connections.

Comment: even after starting Tor there is not much change on IPs. i can see in my firewall traffic is pretty much always routed from frequent IPs, some of these IPs my firewall says first activity to them is about 1 week ago ! if Tor have more than 3000 relay so why i'm not connected to random IPs everytime? maybe Tor 2.4 is backdoored? (i verified signature of package it was valid)